# ratio of reputation - Questions vs Answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was interested in getting to know how much reputation I gained from Questions and how much I gained from Answers?

There is nothing I could find on profile page. (Maybe I missed something).

If it's not there would it be good idea to put in profile page? And is there anything in place to know that?

Comment: You could compare the total score on questions verses total score on answers, but due to the rep cap, you can't really meaningfully compare the rep you've earned from each.

Comment: Hmm, besides curiosity, would it be a real benefit to know? I mean having a feature on the (already quite loaded) profile page? As answers show, you can run a query to satisfy curiosity, but I don't think that should be a general feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a quick and dirty [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374920/reputation-from-posts-separated-by-vote-post-type) that queries out the information.

Running it with your UserId:

```
Accepts               615
Question Up Votes     2080
Answer Up Votes       2000
Question Down Votes   -40
Answer Down Votes     -20
```

This is only approximate, because it doesn't take into account

- any downvotes that would have put your account below 1 rep
- all possible votes, including deleted questions that were deleted > 60 days from the reputation gain.
- reputation in excess of the 200 point daily reputation cap.
- reputation gained or lost through bounties
- penalties for any spam/offensive flags that were accepted
- votes during an extended time-out
- reputation lost from downvoting answers

Comment: Cast downvotes on answers will also factor into the total reputation amount. Since cast downvotes on answers are disguised by design, there is no way to get this actual value.

Answer (score 4):

[This query on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374920/reputation-from-posts-separated-by-vote-post-type) splits it up by

- Accepts
- Question Up Votes
- Question Down Votes
- Answer Up Votes
- Answer Down Votes

Grab your user id and run the query and you should get some useful info.

Note that the data is [updated weekly](https://data.stackexchange.com/help):

> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was yesterday.*

**yesterday was Oct 11, 2015*

Comment: Should have figured that someone would find it on SEDE before I was finished. :)

Comment: Deleted posts and rep-caps interfere a bit, but that's a good first approximation.

Comment: I only ever asked 9 questions, with 18 upvotes total. 18 votes times 5 rep/vote makes 90 rep. How come, this script tells me that I gained 200 rep from questions?

Answer (score 4):

> If it's not there would it be good idea to put in profile page? And is there anything in place to know that?

No, it's not there, and I don't see any benefit about loading the profile page even more with this additional statistical information.

If you're just curious you can run the SEDE queries as proposed in the other answers. But as a feature I'd vote for [status-declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined).