# SEDE for the top percentages of a user

Tags: support, data-explorer

In our profile, we can see whether we are under the top x% of this week, month, quarter etc. Details are [explained here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280036/how-top-user-percentage-for-a-period-is-calculated).

Since only one value is displayed in the profile, I wonder whether there is a SEDE query that shows all percentages for a user, i.e. a query which allows entering a user ID and results in the output of percentage this week, month, quarter, year and overall.

I used Google and tried to find SEDE queries in related meta posts [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294098/what-is-top-this-quarter-based-on) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253292/when-does-the-top-users-statistics-get-updated), but didn't find some.

Comment: Have you tried the [User Reputation Leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow)? It has ranks instead of percentages, though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: thanks. I know those, but I'd like to get the information for a specific user and it'll be hard to find the user in that list.

Comment: The "Type to find users" box above the results list may help you with that.

Comment: SEDE doesn't have access to the reputation history data to tell you exactly when gains and losses happen. You can make a pretty decent estimate with a really complicated query, but there's no direct access to that information.

Comment: @theB: [Not that complicated](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/105259/reputation-history).

Comment: @Bergi - That does ignore several other things. Primarily bounties and the -2 for downvoting answers. More things it misses in my [answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307910/5240004). (It short counts me by 400, over counts you by 4,047 and over counts Jon Skeet by a measly 2,327,899. :) Then again Jon Skeet breaks a lot of queries at SEDE.)

Comment: @theB Are you sure it didn't overcount Jon by 2,147,483,647?

Comment: @canon Are you sure it didn't undercount Jon by 4,294,967,296?

Comment: @canon - We all know that [Jon Skeet's reputation is only so low because of integer overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9138/305827) :) Some ridiculous statistics: Today, according to his profile JS has 815,954 reputation, but without the 200 point daily cap (since it was added), bounties (+8700 received), and negative reputation from his down votes (estimate ~-6500), he'd have in excess of 3,143,853 reputation, and the developers would have to expand the user card for him... Again.